# Whitelist for audio output devices on macOS?

Tags: macos, audio

I often change the audio output device on my MacBook Pro using the button in the top bar. Sometimes the list of available devices will include Apple TV devices from unsuspecting neighbors. Sometimes I accidentally click one of them because the list keeps adding more devices when I try to click on one of my own devices.

Is it possible to have macOS use a whitelist to decide which audio output devices to list? It's super frustrating and probably quite annoying for my neighbors when I accidentally click one of their devices just because of their vicinity.